# Cannot display 5 posts at the page using custom widget in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, posts

I am trying to display 5 posts in widget. All I do is:

```
$post_arguments = array(
     'posts_per_page' => 5,
     'post_status'    => 'publish',
     'post_type'      => 'industry_news'
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $post_arguments );
```

So far so good, in my html i have the following foreach:

```
foreach ($posts_array as $single_post) {
            ?>
            <ul class="tabs-content">
                <li class="tab-active">
                    <div class="article"><a href="#"><img width="260" height="140" class="wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
                        <h3 class="title">
                            <a href="http://example.com/example"
                               title=""><?php $single_post->post_title ?></a>
                        </h3>
                        <p><?php $single_post->post_content ?></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
```

The problem is that the `post_content` and `post_title` are not displaying in the page. Why?

Comment: please use 'echo'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use 'echo'

```
foreach ($posts_array as $single_post) {
            ?>
            <ul class="tabs-content">
                <li class="tab-active">
                    <div class="article"><a href="#"><img width="260" height="140" class="wp-post-image" alt=""></a>
                        <h3 class="title">
                            <a href="http://staging.smartmeetings.com/destinations/98313/south-carolina-food-guide"
                               title=""><?php echo $single_post->post_title ?></a>
                        </h3>
                        <p><?php echo $single_post->post_content ?></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
```